# Why is my code not running/updating my cart on first run of function - Angular

Tags: angular

On my first run of the method addItem, items are added in the localStorage but not in the "cart". When the function is run again, the first and second items are stored.

```
  export class CartService {
  private _subscriptionObservable: Observable<ShoppingCart>;
  private _subscribers: Array<Observer<ShoppingCart>> = new Array<
    Observer<ShoppingCart>
  >();
  private _products: Product[];

 
  private _cartSubscription: Subscription;
  public itemCount: number;
  //TODO: implement storage

  constructor(private _productService: ProductsService) {
    this._products = this._productService.getProducts();
    this._subscriptionObservable = new Observable<ShoppingCart>(
      (observer: Observer<ShoppingCart>) => {
        this._subscribers.push(observer);
        observer.next(this.retrieve());
        return () => {
          this._subscribers = this._subscribers.filter(
            (obs) => obs !== observer
          );
        };
      }
    );
  }

  public get(): Observable<ShoppingCart> {
    return this._subscriptionObservable;
  }
```

This is where I add items on cart.

```
  public addItem(product: Product, quantity: number): void {
    const cart = this.retrieve();

    let item = cart.items.find((p) => p.productId === product.id);

    var cartStorage = localStorage.getItem('cartItems');
    cartStorage = JSON.parse(cartStorage);

    if (item === undefined) {
      var existingEntries = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cartItems'));
      if (existingEntries == null) existingEntries = [];

      var newItem = {
        productId: product.id,
        quantity: quantity,
      };

      localStorage.setItem('newItem', JSON.stringify(newItem));

      existingEntries.push(newItem);

      localStorage.setItem('cartItems', JSON.stringify(existingEntries));
    }


    this.save(cart);
   
    this.dispatch(cart);
```

I call this within the addItem function to update the "cart"

```
    this.retrieve();
```

In this part, I update the cart if there is a content in localStorage

```
  private retrieve(): ShoppingCart {
    const cart = new ShoppingCart();

    var cartStorage = localStorage.getItem('cartItems');
    cartStorage = JSON.parse(cartStorage);

    if (typeof cartStorage !== 'undefined' && cartStorage !== null) {
      console.log('JSON ITEMS:', cartStorage);

      for (var i = 0; i < cartStorage.length; i++) {
        let item = new CartItem();
        item.productId = cartStorage[i]['productId'];
        item.quantity = cartStorage[i]['quantity'];

        cart.items.push(item);
      }
    } else {
      const array = [];
      localStorage.setItem('cartItems', JSON.stringify(array));
    }

    console.log('CART: ', cart);
    return cart;
  }



  private dispatch(cart: ShoppingCart): void {
    this._subscribers.forEach((sub) => {
      try {
        sub.next(cart);
      } catch (e) {
        
      }
     
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you add the `this.save()` function implementation? Also, what calls `addItem()`? Is it a button that call it?

Comment: when you add item you should: 1.-add to cart.items, 2.-storage in localStorage, I don't see in your code when you add to cart.items -you directly get the value of the localstore and add to localstore-. NOTE: Really it's unecessary get always from localstore. Only at very first time (in a ngOnInit). Then you add to cart.items and storage the cart.items. NOTE2: It's looks like a "spagetti code". All functions about localstorage should be in the service.